# How to display twitter widget in full width screen

Tags: html, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, fluid-layout, twitter-widget

I am using bootstrap fluid container layout to display full width content for my website.

I want to display my twitter widget block in the full width but if i try to make it full width using css or jQuery then its not working.

I use the following css to make the widget 100% but its not working.

```
  .timeline-Widget {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 4px;
        max-width: none !important;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Here is screenshot for twitter widget.

[image]

I want to make it full width.

Please provide me appropriate solution for full width twitter widget.

Comment: This wont help. We will need more code to understand your problem. Maybe some screenshots, a fiddle, etc would help. But the above code doesn't help us much to understand what you are facing.

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh , i just edit my question and attach a screenshot of twitter widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some of the code I'm copy-pasting :

CSS

```
iframe[id^='twitter-widget-0'] {
    height:600px !important;
    margin-bottom:10px !important;
    width:100% !important;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('iframe[id^=twitter-widget-]').each(function () {
        var head = $(this).contents().find('head');
        if (head.length) {
            head.append('<style>.timeline { max-width: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; } .timeline .stream { max-width: none !important; width: 100% !important; }</style>');
    }
        $('#twitter-widget-0').append($('<div class=timeline>'));
    })
});
```

Also do refer the [link](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-can-i-extend-width-of-twitter-timeline-to-100-page-size/46101/2). They have other solutions that might work.